# Please allow us to see who the employers are on the career site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, employers

Please allow us to see who the employers are on the career site. A simple list would be fine.

Even better would be if it linked back to jobs.stackoverflow.com and the listings that employer has there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a good idea -- what we might do is have the employers set up a logo and we'll randomly feature a few logos from the list every time.

I am not sure if we can really expose employers in the way you want. But some anonymized search data is safe to share.

We now have **public employer search statistics** for CV holders, under the stats tab -- just click "show detail>>" to expand.

This list is queried dynamically about every hour, and reflects current live data.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you comment on who the 12 are currently?

Comment: 'onboarding' ???

Comment: I suspect the current 12 'employers' are test1 to test12 (since Jeff doesn't know C - otherwise they would be text0 to test11 )

Comment: Even if we don't know their names it would be nice to get some aggregate data about the employers. A few things that occurred to me are: how many are looking in my area, what sort of searches are being run (top X maybe), what search strings caused my resume to be viewed, etc. It would be helpful to know how interesting your resume is to employers to gauge whether or not the site is a good fit for you. Right now it's very hard to know.

Comment: Any update on this one now that the employer side of the beta seems to be in full swing?

Answer (score 6):

I agree. I can only speculate why we presently can't though. Perhaps they feel it would discourage programmers from filing their CV's? If the list of employers is small, and not yet matured, some people may just opt to make an account on linkedin instead. This way, there's a bit of mystery :)

Comment: The number of employers is listed, so your idea is flawed.

Comment: My initial idea was, yes. But considering the service is pretty young, some of those "employers" may be dummy accounts, which means the number could be deceiving.

Comment: You don't even understand your own logic. There is no mystery. We know exactly how many employers there are by the count. This has little to do with the current state of the site, as much as the future. You are arguing two different colliding trains of logic.

Comment: "My initial idea was, yes. But..." means I concede that my initial position was wrong, and now I'm forwarding a different perspective. I'm not arguing two different anythings. As I said, rather clearly, "12 Employers" doesn't mean there are "12 Real, Non Dummy Accounts".

Answer (score 3):

I agree wholeheartedly with this suggestion.

It is definitely valuable for us to know who is hiring before, you know, spending lots of money to be in the recruiting pool!

Ditto in terms of a time investment (how much time should I spend tweaking my CV? How can I optimize it for the types of employers that are here? How often should I check back?)

Answer (score 2):

It would also be really nice to be able to add employers to a list of companies that you would like to work for. Or maybe a list of employer attributes that you are looking for (e.g. small company <50, startup, pet friendly, telecommute only, etc.) Then, when employers search, you could sort results or highlight results based on people that are looking to work at your company specifically or at a company like yours.

It may also help in your sales pitch to certain companies if you could say, "Hey there are 3,000 programmers that are currently saying that they would like to work for you". Even for existing employers you could send updated statistics that say, "Wow! This week 200 potential candidates said they want to work for your company" Think of the PR possibilities.